# What's the best practice to sign maven artifacts in production only?

Tags: java, maven, release, gnupg, maven-central

When me and my team have to push a new maven artifact release to central, the procedure we use is:

```
mvn release:clean
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

And everything works fine.

Of course, the `pom.xml` contains the reference to the maven `gpg` plugin to seal the jars:

```
 ...
<build>
<plugins>
  ....
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>sign-artifacts</id>
        <phase>verify</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>sign</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
   ....
</plugins>
</build>
....
```

Or the `mvn release:perform` fails:

But during development, some of us don't/can't have the `gpg.exe` program installed or the signature key (only the main dev has the correct one that seals the final jars).

So if we locally do `mvn clean install` or other type of commands, the procedure  fails and we cannot have a local modified jar into `.m2` folder while developing.

What is the best practice to do che package signature only when doing the command `mvn release:perform`?

Answer (score 1):

Release and sign the artifact has been already solved. You can use a profile which will be activate the sign plugin. More detail information and the story behind will be found here https://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-generate-pgp-signatures-with-maven/.

```
<profiles>
  <profile>
      <id>release-sign-artifacts</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>performRelease</name>
          <value>true</value>
        </property>
      </activation>
      <build>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-gpg-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>sign-artifacts</id>
                <phase>verify</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>sign</goal>
                </goals>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
  </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: Already tried the solution on that site and does not work. First of all it's syntactly incorrect because says: '[WARNING]  Some problems were encountered while building the effective settings
[WARNING] Unrecognised tag: 'build' (position: START_TAG seen ...</activation>\r\n\t\t\t<build>.'. It does not work even if i use -DperformRelease=true in command line

Comment: @MarcoVasapollo The `profiles` section as described on the page is OK. It doesn't explain how the profile is activated though. It should be activated using `useReleaseProfile` or `releaseProfiles` configuration properties of  deploy plugin, as documented.